# Parse a CSV file using Apache Common skipping 3 lines including a empty line in java

Tags: file, csv, apache-commons, java-io, apache-commons-fileupload

i have a CSV file in below format

[image: CSV file format]

i want to parse it to apache commons-csv parser ,since i have around 20 million of record,so that it will easy to process.Sorry if it is a repeated question,need suggestion.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

it can be done easily with open csv